# Android match_parent backwards compatibility issue won't compile eclipse

Tags: android, compatibility

> Note: When parsing XML resources, Android ignores XML attributes that
>   aren’t supported by the current device. So you can safely use XML
>   attributes that are only supported by newer versions without worrying
>   about older versions breaking when they encounter that code. For
>   example, if you set the targetSdkVersion="11", your app includes the
>   ActionBar by default on Android 3.0 and higher. To then add menu items
>   to the action bar, you need to set android:showAsAction="ifRoom" in
>   your menu resource XML. It's safe to do this in a cross-version XML
>   file, because the older versions of Android simply ignore the
>   showAsAction attribute (that is, you do not need a separate version in
>   res/menu-v11/).

Source: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html

^ Despite this claim eclipse is refusing to compile an unaltered version of fragment basics from the same site [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html).

The error message given is:

> String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value
>   'match_parent').

Is there anyway I can suppress this error within XML, like some kind of silent tag that states they only apply to a specific API level? Ideally I want the project to work in Eclipse and also maintain 1.6 backwards compatibility.

NOTE: All other errors pertain to R not being generated making this the only first generation error.

The manifest file does contain the line

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Comment: 1.5 is too old , check out here number of % active device for 1.5 http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile in the newer API's and the application will still work in the old API, thereby getting rid of these errors, as long as you don't use any of the unsupported features in the .java files without first providing relevant checks. I thought I had to compile against the lowest API not the highest but have tested using a 1.6 AVD to run a project compiled using 4.0 and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using "fill_parent" instead of "match_parent"?  Also you could create a style xml entry with these attributes in place by putting them in values-4 (1.6 android) and values (everything else) folder if you want to have different attribute values for different api levels.

Comment: Thank you for the swift response, if I could vote this up I would. Funnily enough the values-4 is what I thought would work too. It turns out you can **compile in the newer API's and the application will still work in the old API** as long as you don't use any of the unsupported features, I thought I had to compile against the lowest API not the highest.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building your app against API 8 or lower, then you need to use `fill_parent`. That said, most developers these days use API 8 as a *minimum sdk* to support, so you really should consider building your app against the newer APIs.

Comment: Thank you for the swift response, if I could vote this up I would. I will consider the advice but don't want to lose compatibility unless necessary (I still plan to use the higher API specific features). It turns out you can compile in the newer API's and the application will still work in the old API as long as you don't use any of the unsupported features, I thought I had to compile against the lowest API not the highest.